# Set dbtype to null or Int for SQL output parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am returning registrationID as an output of the store procedure. Store procedure can return null or int value.So I am writing following code in my C#.I want to set up dbtype null or int then how can I do that.

```
 p.Add("@TotalRebate", bk.TotalRebate);
 p.Add("@PromotionId", bk.PromotionId);
 p.Add("@RegistrationId", bk.RegistrationId, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
 _db.Execute("InsertBookingNo", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    var registrationId = p.Get<int>("@RegistrationId");
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an Exception? Need more code if we are to help.

Comment: Attempting to cast a DBNull to a non nullable type! Note that out/return parameters will not have updated values until the data stream completes (after the 'foreach' for Query(..., buffered: false), or after the GridReader has been disposed for QueryMultiple)   here is the error

Comment: Edit the Question and add the missing code, including where the Exception is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Still not much to go on but you can try this:

```
var o = p.Get("@RegistrationId");

if(o is DBNull.Value)
{
     //value is null
}
else
{
     registrationId = Convert.ToInt32(o);
}
```

or use nullable int:

```
var registrationId = p.Get<int?>("@RegistrationId");
```

Comment: I added following code   and it is working fine                                                               `p.Add("@PromotionId", bk.PromotionId);
            p.Add("@RegistrationId", bk.RegistrationId, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
            _db.Execute("InsertBookingNo", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            
                var registrationId = p.Get<int?>("@RegistrationId");`